# Why doesnt my code pause music or prevent a song from playing when one song is already playing?

Tags: python

So this is my code;

```
import pygame
from pygame import mixer
import os
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 1300, 800
pygame.mixer.init()    
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
white = [255, 255, 255]
screen.fill(white)
pygame.display.update()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Cupid_song=pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join("music scroller",'onlymp3.to - fifty_fifty___cupid__twin_version___lyrics_-5Ejp7yFZxPM-192k-1689326017.mp3'))
Mortal_Kombat_song=pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join("music scroller",'Mortal Kombat Theme Song.mp3'))

a = False

run = True
while run:
    
    
    keys_pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    clock.tick(60)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             
                
             if event.key == pygame.K_c and a == False:
                 Cupid_song.play()
                 a == True
               
                    
             elif event.key == pygame.K_m and a == False:
                 Mortal_Kombat_song.play() 
                 a == True
                   
             
             elif event.key == pygame.K_p and a == True:
                 Mortal_Kombat_song.stop()
                 Cupid_song.stop()
                 a == False
                 
                
                
             
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                break
            
          
            
pygame.quit()
```

To put it briefly, I was hoping that i can play either song by pressing c for Cupid and M or Mortal Kombat. This would change the variable 'playing" to True, so that when i press the other song it will not fulfill the if statement and the song will not play However, I realize that even if i press m and then c, both songs play. Also, my pause (p) button does not work and the song keeps playing. How do i fix these? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `a == True` vs. `a = True`!

Comment: Holy smokes...actually i dont know, whats the sifference between = and == in this scenario, and how does it affect the code? I tried to get rid of the == in the if statement adn cant so i concluded it should eb == throughout

Comment: In case the above isn't clear, ```a == True``` is used for comparison while ```a = True``` is used for assignment. Here you want to assign a value to ```a``` so that it doesn't enter the if conditional statement.

Comment: Use `a == True` for comparison in the `if`-conditions, but use `a = True` if you want to change the value of `a`. And please try to learn the very basics before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Rabbid76, there is a difference between `==`, which is used for comparison, and `=`, which is used for assignment. Although you are using the correct operator(`==`) in the if-statements when checking if `a == True`, you need to use `=` when trying to assign `True` to `a`(`a = True`), exactly how you have used it initially in `a = False`.

This is what your selection statements would look like:

```py
if event.key == pygame.K_c and a == False:
    Cupid_song.play()
    a = True
                   
elif event.key == pygame.K_m and a == False:
    Mortal_Kombat_song.play() 
    a = True
                       
elif event.key == pygame.K_p and a == True:
    Mortal_Kombat_song.stop()
    Cupid_song.stop()
    a = False
```